# Redirect Hotlinker Without Extensions to Parent Website using .htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

A malicious website is using img tag to insert redirect script in my website.
I have prevented the redirect `using strip_tags()` but the site is consuming all of my bandwidth.
The code he is using is:

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/video/%3Cscript%20type=%22text/javascript%22%20src=%22http://sex3gpvideos.sextgem.com/asss.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E" alt="loading" height="0" width="0" class="thumb"></img>
```

I tried to add this code to prevent the img hotlink but it did't work as there is no extensions in the img link:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mywebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ http://i.imgur.com/qX4w7.gif [L]
```

I want to redirect all websites using my domain in img tags
`<img src="http://mywebsite.com/ANYTHING-HERE"/>` to mywebsite.com

How do I do it using .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just one condition to redirect the referer  to another location:

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://(www\.)?mywebsite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ http://i.imgur.com/qX4w7.gif [L,R]
```

Comment: can I redirect it to mywebsite.com instead of `http://i.imgur.com/qX4w7.gif`
also mywebsite.com don't have ssl and www. Do I still have to add `https?://(www\.)?mywebsite\.com/ [NC]`

Comment: @Maroof **https?** s is optional in the pattern, so it matches both **http** and **https** . and **(www\.)?** means **www** is optional. Yes you can change the destination url to **http://example.com/** instead of the img url